# How to change Content Security Policy directive on IIS

Tags: iis

I am running a WebApp on a Server and I would like to change the Content Security Policy to enable iFrame embedding for all external WebSites.

Currently I get the following error:

```
...in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'
```

How can I allow iFrame embedding for all WebSites on my IIS Server?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use the custom header in the web.config. This setting will mark all the response add the frame setting.

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self';frame-ancestors my-trusty-site.com" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
```